# Xamarin IOS not Finding service

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am unable to find any services affer connecting to a CBPeripheral using xamarin ios with bluetooth.

```
private static readonly UUID SPS_SERVICE = UUID.FromString("0783b03e-8535-b5a0-7140-a304d2495cb7");
public List<CBPeripheral> devices= new List<CBPeripheral>();

public void StartScan
{
    var suuid = CBUUID.FromString(SPS_SERVICE .ToString());
    serviceUuids = new CBUUID[] { suuid };
    Debug.WriteLine("Adapter: Scanning for " + suuid);
}

public eventFiredWhenDiscovered(sender, event)
{
    // Peripheral store as variable in event
    Devices.Add(event.Peripheral);
}

public EventWhenscanTimesOut(sender, event)
{
    foreacch(CBPeripherali in Devices)
    {
         this.central.ConnectPeripheral(i as CBPeripheral, new PeripheralConnectionOptions());
         (i as CBPeripheral).DiscoverServices();
         Sleep(10000); 
         //temp always is null or 0 event even if discover services is put onto a sepereate thread
         int temp = (i as CBPeripheral).Services;
         this.central.CancelPeripheralConnection(i as CBPeripheral);
    }
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin but in Objective C or Swift you have to set a delegate for the peripheral and wait for the callback to say you are connected and then start service and characteristic discovery and again wait for the callback. I am sure there must be a similar process in Xamarin. sleep() is never a good approach.

Comment: I've tried launching an event when a services is found and removed the disconnect incase of a timing issue and it still doesn't work and re located the discover devices to an on connect event